# How to use Sub and GetAtt functions at the same time in CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I created CloudFormation yaml template and I need to use `!GetAtt "TestLambda.Arn"` as part of `!Sub` function in "AWS::ApiGateway::Method" Integration Uri:

```yaml
Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
  Properties:
    RestApiId:
      Ref: "RestApi"
    ResourceId:
      Ref: "TestResource"
    HttpMethod: "GET"
    AuthorizationType: "NONE"
    Integration:
      Type: "AWS_PROXY"
      IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
      Uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/[[place where I want to use !GetAtt "TestLambda.Arn"]]/invocations"
```

As result I want to get a value something like that:

```
"arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/my-endpoint-lambda/invocations"
```

How can I use these functions together and get the desired result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `Fn::` for the nested intrinsic functions if using the `!` short form first. So

```
!Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/$(Fn::GetAtt:[TestLambda, Arn])/invocations"
```

Answer (score 134):

You don't need to use `!GetAtt` here, `!Sub` will automatically unpack values for you if you place them within the place holder:

```
Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${TestLambda.Arn}/invocations
```

This is explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html):

> If you specify template parameter names or resource logical IDs, such as `${InstanceTypeParameter}`, AWS CloudFormation returns the same values as if you used the Ref intrinsic function. If you specify resource attributes, such as `${MyInstance.PublicIp}`, AWS CloudFormation returns the same values as if you used the `Fn::GetAtt` intrinsic function.

Comment: For anyone looking for the JSON equivalent then take a look at the docs linked in the above answer and use a mapping:

`{ "Fn::Sub": [ "www.${Domain}", { "Domain": {"Ref" : "RootDomainName" }} ]}`

Comment: I have to say, this is one of those magical moments where the solution not only exists, but it's easier than expected. Woot!

Answer (score 9):

I know it's an old question, but still the first result in Google:

```
Parameters:
  path:
    Type: String
    Default: something/script.sh
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
Outputs:
  ScriptUrl:
    Description: Script Url
    Value:
      Fn::Sub:
        - ${url}${the_path}
        - {url: !GetAtt Bucket.WebsiteURL, the_path: !Ref path}
```

Answer (score -1):

AWS CloudFormation provides several built-in functions that help you manage your stacks. Use intrinsic functions in your templates to assign values to properties that are not available until runtime.

[Source from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html?shortFooter=true)

The `Fn::GetAtt` intrinsic function returns the value of an attribute from a resource in the template.

**Declaration**

- **JSON**

  - `{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "logicalNameOfResource", "attributeName" ] }`
- **YAML**

  - Syntax for the full function name:
  - `Fn::GetAtt: [ logicalNameOfResource, attributeName ]`
- Syntax for the short form:

  - `!GetAtt logicalNameOfResource.attributeName`

**Note:** Should not confuse with double colon: `Fn::GetAtt` is like `Fn_GetAtt`

Comment: this doesn't actually answer the question as stated