# !GetAtt not working with !Sub in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm trying to create some resources using Cloudformation with serverless framework, In which I need to substitute resource name from another resource. Tried to use `!Sub` but still I couldn't get Arn of another resource created.

Tried all the approaches in this stackoverflow question [How to use Sub and GetAtt functions at the same time in CloudFormation template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986316/how-to-use-sub-and-getatt-functions-at-the-same-time-in-cloudformation-template) to no avail.

I appreciate any help.

```
Resources:
  BasicParameter:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: /data/config-name
      Type: String
      Value:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |

            {
                "filter_configs": [{
                    "stream_name": !GetAtt tpRecordDeliveryStream.Arn,
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "name": "event_name1",
                            "stream": "streamname1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "event_name2"
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            }
      Description: Configuration for stream filters
      Tags:
        project: projectname
        team: data
        owner: owner_name
```

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by using `serverless-pseudo-parameters` serverless plugin. Serverless framework also uses `${}` placeholder and it conflicts with Cloudformation placeholders. serverless-pseudo-parameters solves that by allowing us to replace those place holders with `#{}` which are replaced during `sls deploy` with cloud formation templates

```
Resources:
  streamConfig:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: config_name
      Type: String
      Value:
        Fn::Base64: |
          {
              "filter_configs": [{
                  "firehose_stream_arn": "#{tpRecordDeliveryStream.Arn}",
                  "events": [
                      {
                          "name": "config0",
                          "filter1": "value1"
                      },
                      {
                          "name": "config1"
                      }
                  ]
              }]
          }
      Description: Configuration for stream filters
```

Comment: I didn't know this was the case. Thank you, this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `!Sub |`, instead of

```
 "stream_name": !GetAtt tpRecordDeliveryStream.Arn,
```

the following should be enough

```
 "stream_name": "${tpRecordDeliveryStream.Arn}"
```

The alternative using !Sub in [array notation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html):

```
Value:
  Fn::Base64:
    !Sub 
      - |
        {
            "filter_configs": [{
                "stream_name": "${tpRecordDeliveryStreamArn}",
                "events": [
                    {
                        "name": "event_name1",
                        "stream": "streamname1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "event_name2"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
      - tpRecordDeliveryStreamArn: !GetAtt tpRecordDeliveryStream.Arn
```

Comment: tried them both **with !Sub**  `Invalid variable reference syntax for variable tpRecordDeliveryStream.Arn` and **without !Sub** `Fn::Base64 object must have a String-typed value`

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar What is the definition of `tpRecordDeliveryStream`? Is it some other resource in same template file?

Comment: it is a resource in a different file but part of the same cloudformation deployment
Resources:
  tpRecordDeliveryStream:

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar If its in different stack then you can't reference it like that. Have you exported is in `Outputs` of a stack where they are defined?

Comment: I'm not sure that is the problem, as I can use that in a different place also part of the same deployment

Comment: Ok, just verified, this works Fn::Base64: !GetAtt tpRecordDeliveryStream.Arn, outputs the correct arn

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar I provided alternative way. Have to be careful about indentations.

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar Any luck with the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get anything to work, finally had to be helped by `serverless-pseudo-parameters` serverless plugin and this place holder #{tpRecordDeliveryStream.Arn}, I think the problem is ${} being place holder for both serverless framework and cloudformation and the subsequent conflict